# How to parameterize a linq query?

Tags: linq

I've got a data structure that is a list of hash tables, like so:

```
List<Hashtable> lh = new List<Hashtable>();
```

And a fairly simple LINQ query for this container:

```
var query = from h in lh where h["foo"] == "bar" select h;
```

Is there a way to parameterize the where clause? Something like:

```
var where_clause = where h["foo"] == "bar";
var query = from h in lh where_clause select h;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but yes you can:

```
Func<List<Hashtable>, bool> where_clause = h => h["foo"] == "bar";
List<Hashtable> lh = new List<Hashtable>();
var query = lh.Where(where_clause);
```

Comment: Pretty slick. But can we parameterize the 'h["foo"] == "bar"' itself as a string?

Comment: Sure.  Look for information on Dynamic LINQ.  Start with ScottGu's blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx